# Stop GA reporting from appending the domain to the path when previewing

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics to track data across multiple domains in a single profile.

By default, reporting only shows the path, not the full URL. This makes it quite confusing where multiple pages on our different domains have the same paths (e.g. '/index' or '/about').

To get round this, I've [implemented the filter advised by Google](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en) to display the full URL in reporting:

```
Filter Type: Custom filter > Advanced
Field A: Hostname Extract A: (.*)
Field B: Request URI Extract: (.*)
Output To: Request URI Constructor: $A1$B1
```

This works just fine ; the only downside is that using the 'preview link' button in the reporting always appends the domain, resulting in a 404 error.

[image]

....clicking the 'link preview' icon results in......

[image]

Does anyone know a way around this ; either by preventing GA from appending the domain or a better way of displaying the full URLs in reporting?

Comment: I think your best bet would be to write a browser extension that goes through the page and removes the host name that is set via the domain settings from the links (so that links would actually go to the domain name from the filter). Or ignore it, this is hardly an essential feature.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Eike - I took your advice and wrote a small browser extension for Chrome. Obviously this isn't an essential, but I wanted to address it as our marketing team use the feature so frequently.

The manifest json :

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Analytics cross-domain link shortcut",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Makes the links shortcuts in analytics work when using a 'full url' filter!",
  "content_scripts": 
  [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"], 
      "js": ["myscript.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"  
    }
  ]
}
```

And the script:

```
if (window.opener && document.referrer == "") {

    var currentLocation = window.location.href;

    if(currentLocation.indexOf("www.appendedurl.com") > -1) {

        var newLocation = currentLocation.substr(30); // where '30' is the length of the appended URL

        window.location.href = "http://"+newLocation;

    }
}
```

So it's essentially just snipping off the appended URL (if present) on freshly opened popup windows.